# Conjectured Non-Negativity of a Probabilistic Expression

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This should be embarrasingly simple but I am looking for a way to prove (or disprove) the non-negativity of the following expression for arbitrary distributions with discrete finite support $\mathcal{X}$: $$\sum\limits_{(x,y)\in\mathcal{X}^2}p(x,y)[p(y|x)-p(y)]$$ where the pdf's are joint, conditional and marginal, respectively.

When $p(y|x)=\tilde{p} \mathbf{1}_{[y\neq x]}+(1-\tilde{p})\mathbf{1}_{[y= x]}$, $X\sim Bern(p)$, I have proven the following equality
$$\sum\limits_{(x,y)\in\mathcal{X}^2}p(x,y)[p(y|x)-p(y)]=2 p(1-p) (2\tilde{p}-1)^2\ge 0$$

I have run some simulations in the binary scenario, for some common examples of $p_{Y|X}$ and apart from extreme cases where $p_X\sim Bern(0)$, $p_X\sim Bern(1)$ and $X\perp\!\!\!\perp Y$, I have seen that this sum is positive. Including the equality to 0 scenario which can be trivially achieved when $X\perp\!\!\!\perp Y$, my hunch says this sum should be non-negative.

Thank you!

Edit: I have managed to prove this for all $p_{Y|X}$ when $\mathcal{X}=\{0,1\}$, i.e., $X\sim Bern(p)$. In that case we have
$$\sum\limits_{(x,y)\in\mathcal{X}^2}p(x,y)[p(y|x)-p(y)]=2 p(1-p)\left[1-p_{Y|X}(0|0)-p_{Y|X}(1|1)\right]^2\ge0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $\ y\in\mathcal{X}\ $,
\begin{align}
0&\le\sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}}\big(p(y|x)-\sum_{z\in\mathcal{X}}p(y|z)p(z)\big)^2p(x)\\
&=\sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}}p(y|x)^2p(x)-\big(\sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}}p(y|x)p(x)\big)^2\ .
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\sum_{y\in\mathcal{X}}\sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}}p(x,y)\big(p(y|x)-p(y)\big)&=\sum_{y\in\mathcal{X}}\sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}}p(y|x)^2p(x)-\sum_{y\in\mathcal{X}}p(y)\sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}}p(x,y)\\
&=\sum_{y\in\mathcal{X}}\sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}}p(y|x)^2p(x)-\sum_{y\in\mathcal{X}}p(y)^2\\
&=\sum_{y\in\mathcal{X}}\big(\sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}}p(y|x)^2p(x)-\big(\sum_{x\in\mathcal{X}}p(y|x)p(x)\big)^2\big)\\
&\ge0\ .
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot! As a simple follow up, can we infer that the inequality becomes an equality **only** when $p(y|x)-p(y)=0$ for all $(x,y)\in\mathcal{X}^2$, i.e. $p_{X,Y}=p_X p_Y$? I am assuming $p_X(x)>0$ $\forall x\in\mathcal{X}$ since $\mathcal{X}$ is the support by definition.

Comment: Sort of. The inequality $$0\le\sum_\limits{x\in\mathcal{X}}\big(p(y|x)-\sum_\limits{z\in\mathcal{X}}p(y|z)p(z)\big)^2p(x)$$ holds if and only if $\ p(y|x)-\sum_\limits{z\in\mathcal{X}}p(y|z)p(z)=0\ $ for all $\ x\ $ *such that* $\ p(x)\ne0\ $, so you get $\ p(y|x)=\frac{p(y,x)}{p(x)}= p(y)\ $, or equivalently $\ p(y,x)=p(y)p(x)\ $, for those $\ x\ $.  But $\ p(x)=0\ $ implies that $\ p(x,y)=0\ $, so you also get $\ p(y,x)=$$0=$$p(y)p(x)\ $ for those $\ x\ $ as well.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks!